# Margin inside buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to have some margins inside a button between the text and the borders but I don't know how to specify them.

The only way I know is using android:layout_width="...", but this is not relative to the text size.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want the text to be, the text size has to be defined separately.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use padding to add margin between border and text in button.

Answer (score 113):

If you're looking for this kind of padding on the left and right of this cheeky text : 
[image]

Here is what you do. :

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/she_was_good"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="@string/im_sorry_lol_str" />
```

The part you are looking for is `paddingRight` and `paddingLeft`

Comment: Probably would be best to replace with a non-photoshoped image. That image led me to think you were demonstrating how to have different width boarders on the left and right, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: It was non-photo shopped but the text got kinda viral on reddit. Anyone who wants to do it please do. I have moved on from Android

Answer (score 0):

> To measure its dimensions, a view takes into account its padding. The
>   padding is expressed in pixels for the left, top, right and bottom
>   parts of the view. Padding can be used to offset the content of the
>   view by a specific amount of pixels. For instance, a left padding of 2
>   will push the view's content by 2 pixels to the right of the left
>   edge.

Read more at the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins).